# CodeIgniter hosting live on cpanel error 404 page not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, web-hosting

I am trying to host my web application built with CodeIgniter on a live host.

The folder setup of my website is

```
 --public_html 
      --bplv  
       - - -appication 
        - - -assets 
        - - -system
        - - -.htaccess
        - - -index.php
```

and the htacess file has

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bplv
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and base url is `http://mywebsite/bplv/`, but I am getting "page not found" when I open the website.

[[EDIT-solved]]

turns out its was just a naming convention error. I was using windows while developing locally but the web host was providing linux . So, every time I called a class file called user.php it would search for "U"ser.php with a capital U but it could not find it because it was actually named user.php . Strange that there was no error in windows but there are errors with naming convention in Ubuntu

Comment: And what is baseurl in yur config file??

Comment: I think you are missing one foreslash. Put one of these: either `RewriteBase /bplv/` either `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`. First solution prefered though.

Comment: is bplv a sub domain if so try in url `http://bplv.mywebsite.tdl/`

Comment: Here are some more htaccess files https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter